# Unable to export exe from BGE

Tags: game-engine

I'm really sorry for being such a noob, but I made this game that a bunch of people are waiting for :-/ Upon exporting, it worked on my mac as an app, but then when I opened the blend file on my Windows 10 PC, it gives me these errors and doesn't show up anywhere where I try to save it to when I export the exe. I think it's in the code based on the errors but if someone can actually read this and understand it, maybe you could help me.

I can provide a link to the file via dropbox but I'm pretty sure technically I'm not supposed to do that because all the content in the game is copyrighted and is only supposed to go back onto the site. If someone can help me or point me in the right direction it would be so appreciated and you would be seriously saving my butt..

Note to self: never promise a windows version again because I don't know what I'm doing:(
Below are the errors I get, the movies not being packed is normal because I have to put them in the library resources afterwards, the png not being packed is okay because I ended up reloading a different one, it's all the other stuff and the location -1 that is probably the problem..

[image: Screenshot of errors]

> Read new prefs: C:\Users\alexa\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\config\userpref.blend
>   found bundled python: C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\python
>   read blend: C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\AdventureThroughUmbrafinal.blend
>   Error, region type 5 missing in - name:"File", id:5
>   Error, region type 6 missing in - name:"File", id:5
>   Saving runtime to 'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop\adventure through umbra\AdventureThroughUmbrafinal.exe'
>   Warning: Image 'angloria-2811892.mp4' skipped, movies and image sequences not supported
>   Error: Unable to pack file, source path 'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop....\C:\Users\kbrow\Desktop\AmuletTextures128\flower_Purple_01_128x128V003a.png' not found
>   Warning: Image 'gloamflicker.mov' skipped, movies and image sequences not supported
>   Warning: Image 'gloamflicker.mov.001' skipped, movies and image sequences not supported
>   Warning: Image 'introvid.mov' skipped, movies and image sequences not supported
>   Warning: Image 'introvid2.mp4' skipped, movies and image sequences not supported
>   Info: Packed 1 files
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\game_engine_save_as_runtime.py", line 226, in execute
>       self.report,
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\addons\game_engine_save_as_runtime.py", line 112, in WriteRuntime
>       copy=True,
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.72\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 188, in **call**
>       ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
>   RuntimeError: Error: Unable to pack file, source path 'C:\Users\alexa\Desktop....\C:\Users\kbrow\Desktop\AmuletTextures128\flower_Purple_01_128x128V003a.png' not found
>
> location: :-1
>
> location: :-1

New screenshot of new errors::
[image]

Okay... I repacked that file, got that error related to the .png to go away, but then the exe still won't run on my PC, and also tried to Save as Runtime from the blend file again from the PC, still get some errors that I have no idea what they mean, one including a "Memory Error" it looks like it can't pull the blender player or python script or something::
[image: new screenshot]

ughh bummer town:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out you guys!! If anyone ever comes across this error again, make sure you have the 64 bit version of Blender installed not the 32, which is where I was getting the "Memory Error".. in an effort to make a version that would work on everyone's computer I kicked myself in the butt. It works now!!:D thanks to you guys who took the time to try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some files it can't find that are linked as directories on your computer that don't exist. I would try re-uploading 'flower_Purple_01_128x128V003a.png' and other images. Also, it doesn't seem to be able to accept video files, so that may be a separate problem.

Comment: Yes the movies and the image I'm aware of and aren't the issue because I need to add the movies in afterwards directly to the library, it would still export just those parts would be missing. If anyone knows about the other "linking directories" error in the beginning and the location -1 thing that would be really helpful.. I'm going to try to reinstall blender again but I think I'm making it worse.

Answer (score 0):

save the blend file into a new directory.
copy every image,sound file that your game uses into that directory.
in your .blend game, replace every image,sound with their new copy from inside that folder.

all files must be relative, to be sure , use "*file*->*external data* -> *make all paths relative*" then and move that directory somewhere else and use again "*file*->*external data*->*report missing files*"
if blender complains it means your forgot to remap a file.

once done, the whole folder can be shared.

[According to this tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Making_exe#BlenderPlayer) ,for windows you also need to include the file "blenderplayer.exe" to the new folder from a Windows copy of Blender.

Comment: Hey do you mean manually replace all the images and sounds from that folder? or that the file / make all paths relative function would do this for me? If so I'm in for a long night, lol.. it'd be worth it though if that actually works..finally figured out the cross publishing platform add on though, still getting a weird error, going to post a new screenshot of it.

Comment: the error is about a missing image "flower_purple_01....png" that you probably forgot to copy to your new folder. if you do *pack all into .blend* ,save in the folder and then choose *unpack all into files* and choose *write files to current directory* it will do all the copying for you.

Comment: oh wow, thanks so much! All I had to do was unlink the datablock to that one image (wasn't using it anyway in the game) and an .exe finally showed up in the folder, dropboxing it and testing on my PC, probably have to still add in the videos, but thank you kind stranger!!